# Can't install GCC48 via Homebrew - curl error

Tags: macos, gcc, curl, homebrew, gcc4.8

I am trying to install gcc48 on my Mac OS 10.9 using Homebrew but I keep running into this error:

```
brew install gcc48 --enable-all-languages
==> Downloading ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300259 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
Error: Download failed: ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2
```

Just for sanity check, when I try:

```
wget ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2
--2013-10-27 17:10:07--  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2
           => ‘gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2.1’
Resolving gcc.gnu.org... 209.132.180.131
Connecting to gcc.gnu.org|209.132.180.131|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ...
```

It does not progress any further. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Test it with `curl` instead of `wget`, because that's what `brew` uses.  Try a different mirror site, perhaps.

Comment: It still has issues with curl. I tried a different site by changing the gcc48.rb file and that seems to work. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still unresolved but now as Peter suggested, I tried a different mirror by editing the gcc48.rb file and that seems to have solved the problem. :)